# How to install Abaqus?

Tags: software-installation

I am trying to install Abaqus 6.12 on Ubuntu 12.04. I could mount the .iso file on a virtual drive. When I try to run the setup file, I get the following error:

```
***ERROR. The installation should not be executed from 
      the directory that contains the setup files.
      Please change your current working directory and
      rerun the installation.
```

The following is a part of the setup file I have.

```csh
#!/bin/csh -f
set args=($argv)
@ arglen = $#args
set cmd = $0
set setup_dir = $cmd:h
set my_cwd = $cwd
cd $setup_dir
set setup_dir = $cwd
cd $my_cwd

if ( "$setup_dir" == "$my_cwd" ) then
echo "***ERROR. The installation should not be executed from "
echo "          the directory that contains the setup files."
echo "          Please change your current working directory and"
echo "          rerun the installation."
exit 1
endif
```

How do I install Abaqus on Ubuntu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll do the following steps to ensure that you're not building in the source tree:

```
mkdir $HOME/Abaqus_build_dir
cd $HOME/Abaqus_build_dir
/path/to/your/csh_setup_file
```