# Setup: command not found. Cannot run installer

Tags: software-installation, tcsh, csh

I'm installing Abaqus on Ubuntu. I have extracted the rar files into a directory. In terminal, I navigate to the directory and run the setup file using "sudo /directory_name/setup". Terminal gives me the following error

"Setup: command not found". I have installed csh and tcsh on my system. Could it potentially be a problem with these?

Comment: What are you installing? and how?

Comment: I'm installing Abaqus.  In terminal I'm navigating to the folder and running "sudo /directory_name/setup"

Comment: please edit your question and list down in details all of what you have did to get help

Comment: Question updated.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to install Abaqus?](http://askubuntu.com/questions/454328/how-to-install-abaqus)

Answer (score 0):

It seems you must run first the `csh` terminal, and only then you can run the `setup` file. Insert the command `csh` to run the csh terminal first. There is a tutorial [here](https://sites.google.com/site/abaqus2010/help_0). I don't know what versions of Abaqus and Ubuntu you have.